# Firebase DB updating and pushing simultaneously

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Is there any way to `update` and `push` simultaneously?

I want to update a `key2` in my object and simultaneously push unique keys under `timeline` in a single request `ref().child('object').update({...})`.

```
object
  key1:
  key2: // update
  key3:
  timeline:
    -LNIkVNlJDO75Bv4: // push
    ...
```

Is it even possible or one ought to make two calls in such cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling [`push()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#push) with no arguments will return immediately (without saving to the database), providing you with a unique `Reference`. This gives you the opportunity to create unique keys without accessing the database.

As an example, to obtain a unique push key, you can do some something like:

```
var timelineRef = firebase.database().ref('object/timeline');
var newTimelineRef = timelineRef.push();
var newTimelineKey = newTimelineRef.key;
```

With this, you can then perform a multi-level update which makes use of the new key:

```
var objectRef = firebase.database().ref('object');

var updateData = {};
updateData['object/key2'] = { key: 'value' };
updateData['object/timeline/' + newTimelineKey] = { key: 'value' };

objectRef.update(updateData, function(error) {
  if (!error) {
    console.log('Data updated');
  }
});
```